# What to know in php to translate in node.js?

Tags: php, node.js

I m pretty new to php (not ignorant, but I never did any real project with it). And I have been assigned to translate some php file (some are 1kSLOC) in node.js.

Where can I find a quick start on PHP, I have tried tutorial, but I just need to understand what s going on, not the reason behind, and searching and reading PHP API is quite slow.

EDIT:

It seems I ve been misunderstood, I m not searching to learn php on scratch, I know the basics behind it, I just need something to quickly recall me of the syntax.

[This is a good example of what I m searching for the operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: I ll just go on the API each time solution, if some moderator want to erase this post, go on, I ll ask narrowed question when I can t find by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be a *silver bullet* tutorial describing how to translate custom code.

If you're not familiar with PHP, you'll need to go line by line and interpret the code with the aid of the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net).

Once you've done this, refactor in node.js.

In the end, they're both scripting languages. As such, most of the language constructs (conditionals, loops, etc) are the same.

Comment: Thats the point. If you want to start from scratch with PHP take a look here: http://tut.php-quake.net/ its easy to read and easy to understand.

Comment: I don't believe they are attempting to *learn* PHP, but rather *translate* PHP code.

Comment: I just need a quick refresh of what I know in php, to avoid to research what do each line one after another, the problem. Like Jason said, it s more about translating than learning.